# how to stream the video capture of WEB RTC WOWZA in VLC or PYTHON OPENCV ,

Tags: python, opencv, stream, wowza

i used Wowza Streaming Engine for stream the camera of my drone using RTMP protocol  , and i Convert RTMP to WebRTC With Wowza Streaming Engine (with UDP protocol )   to reduce the **Latency** , this step work perfectly ,you can see it in this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8rj0.png)

Now i want to show this screen video  of WebRTC with python language using opencv : like that

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('the URL of WebRTC')
```

how can be get the  URL of WebRTC ???

Please i need your help .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) library. You'll need something to create Python bindings to WebRTC unless you want to do that yourself. I have not used this library myself, but it appears to give you what you are looking for. Many other libraries only cover audio, not video.

Comment: I already installed aiortc library, but how can be use it to stream with Python , must be an URL to get the stream from WebRTC , FYI i need this to do image processing with opencv .

Comment: please if you have a video or tutorial if you have it